# Send SQL JSON via Python to Rest API

Tags: python-3.x

i'm trying to send some data to a REST API via requests.
I thought its a good idea building the whole JSON in a MS-SQL Function because it's a little bit complicated.

In my Python Script i'm connecting to SQL DB via pyODBC and catch this SQL-JSON.

Next Step would be to build the request but here i'm struggling with the data types and run out of ideas what to do.

Here is what i tried so far

result from pyodbc is datatype list, so i extract the single JSON string.

```
    result = cursors.fetchall()
    data = result[0][0]
```

So i get a Python string in correct JSON Format in datatype string.
Now i'm trying to get this string in a valid python JSON object with json.loads() which works without problems.

```
    try:
        json_object = json.loads(data)
    except json.JSONDecodeError as e:
        print('Error:', e)
```

Now i'm trytin to send this JSON Object via requeests to the API and this doesn't work.
I have tryied several options, send this object as json, data ... i've tried with string as data etc.
Evereytime  i get the error "Malformed body", so the webservice does not accept my JSON as JSON.

```
requests.post(url, headers=headers, auth=auth, json=json_object)
... requests.post(url, headers=headers, auth=auth, data=json_object)
... requests.post(url, headers=headers, auth=auth, data=data)
```

I'm wondering how complicated it ca be to send an almost done JSON String in python. Is it a stupid idea to build the JSON in SQL Server before executing the script or is my bad understandig on datatype conversion the only problem?

Comment: headers should have `{"Content-Type':"application/json"}`

Comment: then also set `data = json. dumps(data)`

Comment: thanks Dean, Header was set correct, an i tested the json.dumps(data) which also didn't work

Answer (score 0):

found then problem in encoding of MS-SQL JSON, which is not UTF-8.

```
json_object = json.dumps(json.loads(data))
```

solved the problem. Not very beautiful but works.